# BlackBerry Problem with urls

Tags: url, blackberry, netbeans, java-me

i developed a j2me application that access url from the app, its working very well on nokia mobiles but when i installed it on a blackberry device i couldnt access the web, i dont know how to let the BB device to access the web

Comment: and exception trace is ?

Comment: there is no error it just blocks the url to be opened

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention interface with url in blackberry. The BlackBerry knowledge center has an article that explains how to make Http Connections: [What Is - Different ways to make an HTTP or socket connection](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0)

which device you are using and what OS version?